# Error al insertar en base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema al insertar en la base de datos ciertos campos

**Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**

Tengo muchos formularios en mi app en `php` y nunca me ha dado este problema.

He hecho copia y pega de otros `INSERT` que tengo, modificando los campos, y sigue sin funcionar

```html
$sql = "INSERT INTO empresa (fecha,nombre,cif,direccion,localidad,postalCode,provincia,email,pass,lat,lng,registerActivation,claveVerify,userPlan)
VALUES ('$fecha','$nombre','$cif','$direccion','$localidad','$postalCode','$provincia','$email','$password','$lat','$lng','$registerActivation','$claveVerify','$userPlan')";
```

He probado a reducir el numero de valores a 2 de la siguiente forma, y el error sigue siendo el mismo

```html
$sql = "INSERT INTO empresa (fecha,nombre) VALUES ('$fecha','$nombre')";
```

Añado forma de mi tabla a petición de @Alfabravo

```html
CREATE TABLE `empresa` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `cif` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `localidad` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `postalCode` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `provincia` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `lat` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `lng` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `registerActivation` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `claveVerify` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `userPlan` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Dice que el numero de campos que quieres ingresar no es igual al numero de values, en el primero tienes 14 y en el segundo tienes 15, revisa bien la consulta.

Comment: mmm, los he contado 4 veces y me salen 14 en los 2

Comment: el error dice que no estas proporcionando una cantidad de datos igual a la que la tabla contiene, revisa cuantos campos tiene tu tabla.

Comment: Aparentemente está bien. Lo único que se me ocurre es que te asegures que las variables $ contengan datos y no estén vacíos. Prueba a mostrarlas primero con echos o lo que sea a ver si contienen valores.

Comment: `$sql = "INSERT INTO empresa (fecha,nombre) VALUES ('$fecha','$nombre')";` Prueba con eso por si acaso. En fecha y nombre como columna ponle esta comilla ` al princpio y fin de cada nombre de columna

Comment: He revisado los campos de mi tabla, tiene 14, `tiene 15 si contamos un campo id con autoincrement`

Comment: Entonces deberías indicar en la query el `id` con su `VALUE` en `DEFAULT`: `$sql = "INSERT INTO empresa (id,fecha,nombre) VALUES (DEFAULT,'$fecha','$nombre')";`

Comment: Pon valores que no sea campo Fecha, si funciona ese es el problema, si no, fijate en si tu tabla empresa está bien escrita

Comment: Por favor, incluye en tu pregunta la definición de tu tabla empresa. Como texto, no como imagen.

Comment: He añadido la forma de mi tabla

Comment: Lo he solucionado, era un problema con un trigger en phpyadmin, lo he borrado y ya funciona perfectamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba poniendo NULL antes de la variable $fecha. No debería dar error.

```html
$sql = "INSERT INTO empresa (fecha,nombre,cif,direccion,localidad,postalCode,provincia,email,pass,lat,lng,registerActivation,claveVerify,userPlan)
VALUES (NULL,'$fecha','$nombre','$cif','$direccion','$localidad','$postalCode','$provincia','$email','$password','$lat','$lng','$registerActivation','$claveVerify','$userPlan')";
```

Comment: jvmartinez está en lo cierto. Si pones NULL cómo  he indicado, en la consulta debe figurar el campo id.

Answer (score 0):

Este tipo de error ocurre cuando el número de columnas no coincide cuando inserta registros en la tabla. 
Suponiendo que tu id AUTO_INCREMENT es el primer campo quedaria asi:

```
<?php
$sql = "INSERT INTO empresa (id,fecha,nombre,cif,direccion,localidad,postalCode,provincia,email,pass,lat,lng,registerActivation,claveVerify,userPlan)
VALUES ('','$fecha','$nombre','$cif','$direccion','$localidad','$postalCode','$provincia','$email','$password','$lat','$lng','$registerActivation','$claveVerify','$userPlan')";
?>
otra forma de hacer esta sentencia es
<?php
$sql = "INSERT INTO empresa VALUES ('','$fecha','$nombre','$cif','$direccion','$localidad','$postalCode','$provincia','$email','$password','$lat','$lng','$registerActivation','$claveVerify','$userPlan')";
?>
```